# Spring boot security regresa html 200 ok , cuando hago una peticion @Postmapping

Tags: java, spring-security

En esta clase cuando elimino del metodo configure estas lineas .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin() la request sirve de forma que quiero pero si las agrego me regresa un html

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    private final AppUserService appUserUervice;
    
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http
             .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("api/v1/registration/**")
             .permitAll()
             //.anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin() ;
            
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
        
        
    
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        
        DaoAuthenticationProvider  provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserUervice);
        
        return provider;
    }
    

}
```

El problema es que estoy siguiendo un tutorial y en este las linas .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()  estan agregadas y si sirve el metodo

Answer (score 0):

ya descubri cual era el error le faltaba un "/" en esta parte
.antMatchers("api/v1/registration/**") lo cambie por
.antMatchers("/api/v1/registration/**")